# How does Google Analytics find out what company is visiting a website?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics I found that it is possible to create a custom report including a visitors `Service provider` which basically shows you what company a visitor is visiting from. I guess this is somehow tied to the Ip-Adress.

How is Google Analytics doing this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "whois" service allows anyone to identify the owner of an IP address range. I would assume that their data is based on that.